# Matlab shared session blocked by stale information about previous session with same name

Tags: matlab

I've been using Matlab shared sessions so that a Python program can connect to the engine and run some stuff, repeatedly, without the time delay of starting up a new Matlab instance every time. I use a hardcoded name so the Python program knows how to find the Matlab engine.

I use:

```
matlab -nojvm -nosplash -r matlab.engine.shareEngine('my_session_name')"
```

Today I had to `kill` the MATLAB process because... well because it was taking too long to do something and I wanted to start fresh. Let's not dwell on that bad decision.

When I attempted to start another copy, using the same session name, it gave me this error:

```
Error using matlab.engine.shareEngine (line 41)
MATLAB session 'my_session_name' already exists.  Current MATLAB session is now shared with default
name 'MATLAB_15886'.
```

Rather than accept this and change my hardcoded name, I figured I'd just find whatever file Matlab was using the cache this information, and delete it. Google failed me. I was unable to find anyone talking about this error, let alone how to solve it. Closing all Matlab instances on the machine did not help. I'm stuck.

Running on RHEL 6.2 with Matlab 2017a.

How can I convince Matlab to let me name a new session with the old name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab keeps information about the session in two places.

First, it creates `/tmp/my_session_name` as a "domain socket".

Second, it creates `/tmp/${USER}_edr/matlab/R2017a/transport/matlab_endpoint_lookup_${RANDOM_STUFF}`. This directory will contain a pid file and `my_session_name.epf`.

I can't be sure what steps are absolutely necessary, but deleting the "endpoint_lookup" directory and the "domain socket" file will let Matlab reuse the session name. I suspect the "domain socket" is the real critical piece.

I'd be careful not to delete information for an active session. That probably doesn't end well.

I figured this out by inspecting what files Matlab writes to when starting with a new session name. Running:

```
strace -f -o matlab.trace matlab -nojvm -nosplash -r "matlab.engine.shareEngine('another_session_name')"
```

Then I grep'ed for anything it was writing to:

```
grep " open(" matlab.trace | grep -v "RDONLY"
```

That produced a very short list to investigate.

I hope this saves someone an hour of their time.

Comment: After repeating this cycle, I concluded that it is indeed the "domain socket" file that is the real block. So definitely try just deleting that first.